# In Python 3.6, why don't string literals (using the same quote type) work inside interpolated strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Basic example:

```
>>> table = {'username': 'John Doe'}
>>> msg = f'Hello {table['username']}'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    msg = f'Hello {table['username']}'
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> msg = f"Hello {table['username']}"
```

Why doesn't it work when both the format string and the inner string literal use the same quote type (both single-quoted or double-quoted)? Is this a bug in Python 3.6, or is this intentional?

**edit:** To make it clear why I'm asking this, something like this works fine in C#:

```
using System;
public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello {"world"}");
    }
}
```

[Proof](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgBgARwIwG4CwAoOBmFVANhQCZCB2JAbxyXpQLRLgBZCAOACgEoa6GgtAE4uAEgBEACQCmAGzkB7GhIDuisHIAmEgL4SeWbIN05dQA==)

Comment: How could Python know that you didn't mean the second `'` to be the end of the string without reading your mind, or at least speculatively trying to parse all possible quote pairs in the entire file and seeing if exactly one of them is legal syntax?

Comment: Also, this is part of the reason triple-quoted strings exist—so you can use both `'` and `"` within the same string (or use either one arbitrarily without paying attention to which one you used to quote it) without needing any escaping. Of course occasionally a string needs `"""` inside it, so you still occasionally need escaping, but it goes from very common to very rare.

Comment: @abarnert By seeing that it's inside the `{}`? In C# for example, you can include arbitrary expressions (including string literals) inside an interpolated string expression, and it works fine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because the expression is inside `{}`. See above

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Not if it's a format string. If it starts with `f'` or `f"` and it sees a `{`, then an expression must follow and it must be closed with a `}`.

Comment: @JamesKo C# isn't LL(1) parseable. It's nicer than C++, but it's still not something you can parse in your head after reading the rules one time and keeping a reference. Python is.

Comment: Also, notice that whatever code colorizer SO uses failed to parse your C#.

Comment: @abarnet So what. SO colorizers are not real parsers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't know what a "real parser" is, but I know I can bang out a parser for an LL(1) language, and I can trace through what it's doing in my head, while for a language like, say, C++, a team of experts needs thousands of lines of hand-coded parser, and I sometimes can't figure out what it's doing even from its error messages. If that means Python doesn't need a real parser, then not needing a real parser is a good thing.

Comment: @abarnet Do you know how the SO colorizers work? They aren't language parsers. They are crude. We are talking about SO colorizers in this little thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan From a quick search, SO uses [code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), which has a default parser and lexer, custom lexers for a bunch of languages, and parser hooks for a few languages, and code to transform the tree into a DOM tree. So, sure, it's a crude and simple parser, but it's still a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with interpolated strings. An interpolated string is read the same as any other string literal<sup>*</sup> and then interpolated, and you can't put unescaped quote characters in the middle of any string:

```
>>> msg = 'Hello {table['username']}'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    'Hello {table['username']}'
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> msg = 'Hello 'world''
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    msg = 'Hello 'world''
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is exactly why we have a choice of two different quote characters—and, when that isn't enough, triple-quoted strings. And of course escaping.

So, why can't Python be smarter here? Think about what "smarter" would mean. Assuming it can't read your mind, it would have to parse every possible way that pairs of quotes could be matched up if some of them were skipped and then figure out which one made for a valid result. That might not seem too bad for a simple one-liner at the interactive interpreter, but if it had to do that across an entire file, every time you run a non-trivial script or import a module with more than a few quotes in it, it would take minutes to try all the parses, and the result could well be ambiguous anyway.

Could they instead add special rules for handling quotes only in interpolated strings, only inside currently-open braces (but not double braces, of course, because those are escapes), and so on?

Sure, That wouldn't make the parser exponential, just more complicated. But more complicated is not good either.

The fact that Python has a simple set of rules that anyone can knock out a LL(1) implementation of—and, maybe even more importantly, that anyone can keep in their heads and work through—is a major feature of the language as compared to, say, C++. So every time there's a tradeoff between nice syntactic sugar vs. keeping the parser simple, it has to be thought through, and the answer is always keeping the parser simpler. In fact, this was [an explicit decision in the Python 3 transition](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3099/):

> Simple is better than complex. This idea extends to the parser. Restricting Python's grammar to an LL(1) parser is a blessing, not a curse. It puts us in handcuffs that prevent us from going overboard and ending up with funky grammar rules like some other dynamic languages that will go unnamed, such as Perl.

Also, of course, that would be a difference between f-strings and `str.format`, which would be another rule to learn, and to relearn every time you come back to Python after a few months away. Which is a different rule from the Zen: Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your analysis. It knows it is an interpolated string. The parsers could switch between parsing rules when it encounters curly braces. I don't see ambiguity here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Did you stop reading at some point? The last 5 paragraphs are all about that point.

Comment: I didn't stop reading. I am not convinced by your analysis. Are you claiming that the parsing quotes inside the interpolated part cannot be done LL(1)? Or that the designers chose not to do so?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My guess would be that someone suggested adding it, someone else asked "Can anyone parse that in LL(1) with relatively simple rules?", and the lack of a positive answer was enough; nobody actually sat down and proved it was impossible. That's how Python's development model generally works. But the entire discussion is available in the archives of the python-ideas and python-dev lists and the bug tracker, if you want to find out the details.

Comment: Given that you are the one who wrote the answer I would have thought that the onus was on you to find out he details. This just reads like waffle. Sorry.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Seeking out documentation and linking and copying it is one thing; reading through months of discussion just to make sure that a proof that almost certainly isn't there actually isn't there is a waste of time.

Comment: Answering a question when you don't know the answer also seems a waste of time to me. I've made my point. I've said enough.

Answer (score -2):

the problem is that it is a string and you did not do the interpolation, because that was the error, you should use string.Template to define a format string or you can use the format method of str class with which you can substitute values inside of a String

> 'Hello {table['username']}' this is bad

you can use 'Hello {username}'.format(username=table['username'])

see for more information: [here](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/)